How to allow any AWS account to access my S3 bucket
I have a third party system that I can ask to upload files to an S3 bucket of my choice. The code the system uses is
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
bucket.put_object(Body=data_log,Key='log.txt')

The AWS credentials the system uses belong to an AWS account that I cannot administrate. Also, I am (for now) not allowed to change the used AWS credentials nor the used code.
So I tried to create an s3 bucket like this:
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket <MYBUCKET> --region eu-central-1 --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint="eu-central-1" 
aws s3api delete-public-access-block --bucket <MYBUCKET>
aws s3api put-bucket-ownership-controls --bucket <MYBUCKET> --ownership-controls 'Rules=[{ObjectOwnership="BucketOwnerPreferred"}]'
aws s3api put-bucket-acl --bucket <MYBUCKET> --acl public-read-write

But when I run the code, I get the error message
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

So the big question is, how can I configure my s3 bucket to allow access from a user in a different account WIHOUT changing that user's policy in his account.
I can get the code to upload to my s3 bucket by changing it to
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', config=Config(signature_version=UNSIGNED))
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
bucket.put_object(Body=data_log,Key='log.txt')

But that, unfortunately, does not solve my problem as I cannot do that on the productive system.
Also, I found that I can attach the policy
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PolicyForAllowUploadWithACL",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<MYBUCKET>/*"
        }
    ]
}

to the s3 bucket and the policy
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PolicyForAllowUploadWithACL",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<MYBUCKET>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

to a user in a second AWS account of mine.
If I run the upload code with that second account it works, too. But again, that does not solve my problem as I cannot do that on the productive system (I cannot change the used AWS credentials, and I cannot administrate the policies of the used user).

Did you try allowing principal "AWS": "*" in the S3 bucket policy alone, without the corresponding IAM policy change? If that is insufficient then I don't think this is possible without asking the client to send the request unauthenticated (or modifying their IAM policy).

Your situation seems to be:

An S3 object will be uploaded from somebody else's AWS Account
You want to allow that upload
You do not want to allow anybody else permission to upload an object

The best way to do this would be:

Find out the AWS Account number of the system doing the upload
Add a Bucket Policy to your bucket that permits uploads from this AWS Account

The bucket policy would look something like:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT-NUMBER>:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<MYBUCKET>/*"
        }
    ]
}

This policy allows the given AWS Account to upload an object to your bucket. You will need to disable Block S3 Public Access enough so that you can add this Bucket Policy to your bucket.
In fact, if the other system is always uploading a file called log.txt, you could further limit the permissions by setting the resource to:
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<MYBUCKET>/log.txt"


Hey John!
thanks for the suggestion! Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that adding this policy to my bucket will grant access to the root user of the other account. As the user I want to give access to is not the root user, the other account's root user would need to attach a policy to the actual user (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html and my original question).
Sorry I forgot to mention that the account in question is not a root user.

It is actually saying: "Trust the permissions in this AWS Account. If a user in that account has permission to PutObject into this bucket, then allow it to happen." This is a cross-account operation, so permissions are required both in the 'source' account (that is uploading the data) and also on the 'destination' bucket.

Fair enough. But is there a way to tell my S3 bucket: "Whoever wants to access, just let it happen"?

You can certainly change the bucket policy to "Principal": "*", which would allow anyone in the world to upload objects to the bucket. I would not advise this, since you could receive unwanted files and viruses.

Thank you again for your input. I just tried it out, but that does not work unless I attach a policy to the user in question (which I cannot do in my scenario).
So I fear I will have to request a code change in the third party system, right?

If the IAM entity that is performing the upload has not been granted permission to upload to your bucket (or permission to upload to ANY bucket), then you would need to use "Principal": "*" in your Bucket Policy, which will allow anyone to upload to the bucket. That is a trade-off you might need to accept. If this does not work then, yes, it would require changes in the source system to grant that IAM entity permission to upload to your bucket.
